# JQuery Calendar and JS arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Please help. I have this issue using the Calendar feature in JQuery. I retrieve an arrays of dates from database using json encode, and then try to highlight this dates in the calendar, but is not working.

I tried to format the dates array as the example I followed from a webpage (that's why I reorganize the order of day-month-year and  extract zeros from the day and time variables) My code:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         //global variable. Will store scheduled tours dates
        highlightDates = [];
        $.getJSON('../mod/calendar.php',function(data){
          window.console && console.log(data);
          window.console && console.log(data.length);
          for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            //extracting year, month and day from JSON string
            var yearDate = [];
            var monthDate = [];
            var dayDate = [];
            yearDate.push(data[i].tour_date.substr(0,4));
            monthDate.push(data[i].tour_date.substr(5,2));
            //Erase the '0' at left of integer
            var monthDate = parseInt(monthDate, 10);
            dayDate.push(data[i].tour_date.substr(8,9));
            //Erase the '0' at left of integer
            var dayDate = parseInt(dayDate, 10);
            //Converting to dates string
            highlightDates.push(dayDate+'-'+monthDate+'-'+yearDate);
          }
            window.console && console.log(highlightDates);
        });
      });

$.noConflict();
//Highlight dates which has tours scheduled using JQuery Calendar (datepicker)
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
      var month = date.getMonth()+1;
      var year = date.getFullYear();
      var day = date.getDate();

      // Change format of date
      var newdate = day+"-"+month+'-'+year;

      // Set tooltip text when mouse over date
      var tooltip_text = "New event on " + newdate;
      window.console && console.log(highlightDates);

      // Check date in Array
      if(jQuery.inArray(newdate, highlightDates) != -1){
        return [true, "highlight", tooltip_text ];
      }
    return [true];
    }
  });
});
  </script>
  <style>
    .highlight {
      background: #29f274 !important;
      color: #ffffff !important;
    }
  </style>
```

this is the console output:

[image]

and this is the console output using a test array:
[image]

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting dates in first console.log()? are you getting dates in second console.log()? For testing.. forget about multiple dates.. is it working with one date? I don't see the setDate() method that sets a date.

Comment: Please provide sample of the data in `highlightDates` as per [mcve]

Comment: Yep. I'm getting the array of dates from database, and yes, when I use a n array for testing, it works fine @Nawed

Comment: You have 2 sets of functions and both have a console.log(). I believe the second one is not showing anything. The reason, I suspect, it is not working is because you have 2 asynchronous codes. You are assuming the first one will wait for the dates to come back and then the second function will use it. But in reality the second function is called right away while the first function is still getting dates.... hence the console.log() in second function has no dates.

Comment: @NawedKhan that was my guess... I'm trying to use a callback or promises, but I have no idea how to make it work, though I try to find out through some examples. Suggestions are welcome!

Comment: just move the second function inside the first function, right after the console.log. Or enclose datepicker code in a function and call that function inside the first one.

Comment: @Rodrigo Have you tried putting the $('#datepicker') code after the for loop in the callback of the $.getJSON method?

Comment: Please don't provide images of code or data). Nobody can copy from them to test your code. See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Sarah Yes, I tried various combinations... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solve my problem, and I want to share if it works for someone else...

The main thing in my case, is that the date retrieved from MySQL database comes in the form yyyy-mm-dd and I need it in the form dd-mm-yyyy (regardless you can change the date entry format in the Daypicker plugin)

So, for the data retrieved from database I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  allDates = [];//global variable. Will store scheduled art dates
  $.getJSON('../mod/calendar.php',function(data){
    window.console && console.log(data);
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
       //extracting year, month and day from JSON string
       var yearDate = [];
       var monthDate = [];
       var dayDate = [];
       yearDate.push(data[i].art_date.substr(0,4));
       monthDate.push(data[i].art_date.substr(5,2));
       //Erase the '0' at left of integer
       var monthDate = parseInt(monthDate, 10);
       dayDate.push(data[i].artdate.substr(8,9));
       //Erase the '0' at left of integer
       var dayDate = parseInt(dayDate, 10);
       //Converting to dates string
       allDates.push(yearDate+'-'+monthDate+'-'+dayDate);
        window.console && console.log(allDates);
    }
//And for the calendar I have

  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd",
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var month = date.getMonth()+1;
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var day = date.getDate();
        // Change format of date
        var search = year+"-"+month+'-'+day;
        window.console && console.log(search);
        for(var i = 0; i < allDates.length; i++){
          window.console && console.log(allDates[i]);
          if(search == allDates[i]){
            return [true, 'highlight', 'Arts scheduled'];
          }
        }
        return [true, '', ''];
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Hope this helps someone!